# How to call a callback function in spfx react.js within the Chart.js controls from the pnp framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, chart

I'm programming a SPFx Webpart in React.js and I'm using the spfx controls from chart.js.

Now I want to change the labels at the x axis. Therefore I need to call a callback function to get the corresponding values back. I tried it with callback: function(value,index,values) return yLabel[value].

Here is the code so far:

```
    <div> <ChartControl
                    type={ChartType.Scatter}
                   data={{
                      datasets:[{
                         data:[
                        { 
                          x: 4,
                          y: 0
                        },
                        {
                          x: 5,
                          y: 1
                        },
                        {
                          x: 4,
                          y: 2
                        },
                        {
                          x: 5,
                          y: 3
                        },
                        {
                          x: 3,
                          y: 4
                        },
                        {
                          x: 5,
                          y: 5
                        }]     
                      }]
                   }}
                   options={{
                    scales:{
                      xAxes:[{
                        ticks:{
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        ticks:{
                           callback: function(value, index,values){
                              return value
                           }
                        }
                      } 
                      }],
                      yAxes:[{
                        beginAtZero:true
                      }]
                    }
                   }}
                   loadingtemplate={()=> <div>Please wait...</div>}
                  
                     />
                </div>
```

I don't know how in the spfx world such a callback function should look like.

Best regards

Matthias